# How to create an inner join with mysql and JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm new to working working with a JDBC. I've got an assignment in which I have an Employee table and a salary table in MySQL. They both intersect on employee ID.

What I want is to get everything from the employee and salary tables. My MySQL code is as follows and appears to work fine:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getEmployeeSalary;
CREATE PROCEDURE getEmployeeSalary ()
SELECT * FROM oop_employees
INNER JOIN oop_salaries ON
oop_employees.emp_no = oop_salaries.emp_no
ORDER BY salary DESC;
```

My only issue is how to translate that across to Java.

I've currently got an Employee class as below with getters and setters for each element:

```
public class Employee {

//private fields to store data

    private int emp_no;         
    private Date birth_date;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String gender;
    private Date hire_date;

    public Employee(int emp_no, Date birth_date, String first_name, String last_name, String gender, Date hire_date) {
        super();
        this.emp_no = emp_no;
        this.birth_date = birth_date;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.hire_date = hire_date;
    }
```

If you have an suggestions how I should attempt it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to run a `SELECT` statement using JDBC? Or are you asking how to call a stored procedure using JDBC? In either case, there are many examples available on the web. Try searching for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ResultSet class (part of the java.sql), like

```
ResultSet set = dbConnection.createQuery("here your query");
while(set.next){
    String employeeId = set.getString("id");
    System.out.println(employeeId);
}
```

I this helped in your problem